# Как задать один Font-family всем элементам на странице?

Tags: шрифты, css

Я пытался написать `body { font-family:'нужное'; }`, но не работает. На `htmlbook` написано, что `font-family` наследуется. Но у меня что - то не получается.

Comment: Всё оказалось просто, в проекте был подключен reset.css, в нем для всех элементов было установлено font:inherit; я закомментировал эту строку и всё стало ок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А если:

```
* { font-family:'нужное'; }
```

Или так:

```
html, body {font-family:'нужное'; }
```

А вообще должен работать и ваш вариант.

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает

Comment: И так и так пробовал, сейчас даже отдельно элементу попробовал установить font-family,всё равно не работает. Но самое интересное, что есть у меня класс .logo, так вот если ему задать : font-family:"Comic Sans MS"; например, то он изменит шрифт элемента с .logo Comic Sans MS

Answer (score 3):

> Всё оказалось просто, в проекте был
> подключен reset.css, в нем для всех
> элементов было установлено
> `font:inherit;` я закомментировал эту
> строку и всё стало ок.

Это делать не следовало. Устанавливая для всех элементов значение "inherit" для свойства "font" вы сможете наследовать установленный шрифт. 
Процедура такая:

1. Устанавливаем для всех элементов `inherit`
2. Ниже для body задаем нужное значение

   ```
   {
     font-family:'нужное'; 
   }
   ```

Причина, по которой не получалось установить наследуемый шрифт в вашем случае, заключается в разном "весе" значения "font" и "font-family". 
В данном случае есть 2 решения:

1) В reset.css вместо

```
{
    font:inherit;
}
```

пишем

```
{
  font-family:inherit;
  font-size:inherit;
  font-style:inherit;
}
```

и в body

```
{ 
  font-family:'нужное'; 
}
```

(как раньше)

2) Не трогаем reset.css, но тогда в "body" задаем параметры так же для "font".

Пример:

```
body {
  font:normal 12/14px Arial,Helvetica,Garuda,sans-serif;
}
```

Предпочтительнее первый вариант, иначе в каждом элементе, где понадобится другой стиль, для шрифта нужно будет переопределять "font" целиком вместо "font-size" скажем или же использовать "`!important`".

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
* { font-family: 'нужное' !important; }
```

Пример [без](http://jsfiddle.net/hACKb/) и [с](http://jsfiddle.net/hACKb/1/) !important.

Comment: А, действительно, как я мог забыть про вес. Так должно сработать.

Answer (score 0):

Была та же проблема, пока я не заметила, что забыла поставить запятые между названиями шрифтов:

```
body {
 font: 12px Arial, Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

Как поставила запятые между шрифтами - все стало наследоваться.